# Sum reminiscent of $(1+x)^N$ (binomial theorem)

Tags: summation, binomial-theorem

I stumbled upon this sum while working on my thesis:

$$\sum_{k=0}^N  \binom{N}{2k} x^k$$

I know that

$$\sum_{k=0}^N  \binom{N}{k} x^k = (1+x)^N$$

But when it comes to the sum above I'm lost. Is there any way to solve it?

**PS** $|x|<1$ and N is an even number. Also, as [Semiclassical](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/137524/semiclassical) remarked, the sum actually runs up to $N/2$:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{N/2}  \binom{N}{2k} x^k$$

Comment: It seems worth noting that the summation really only runs up to $k=\lfloor N/2\rfloor$ since the binomial coefficient vanishes otherwise. On that note,  is $N$ assumed to be even versus odd?

Comment: @Semiclassical $N$ is even. I added that detail to the question. You are right, it runs up to $\left \lfloor{N/2}\right \rfloor $

Comment: There's usually no harm in letting the index run past $N/2$. In fact, I would typically prefer to let the index $k$ run over all integers.

Comment: @Hurkyl This is interesting. So $\binom{N}{k}$ is defined to be $0$ when $k>N$?

Comment: @valerio92: Yep; and also when $k < 0$. (assuming that $k$ is an integer and $N$ is a nonnegative integer)

Comment: @Hurkyl Never mind, found it: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialCoefficient.html

Comment: @Hurkyl Oh ok, thanks. I saw the comment only now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the comment about the sum not even being defined for $2k>N$, I think that you could legitimately rewrite your question as $$\sum_{k=0}^N  \binom{N}{k} {\sqrt{x}}^k$$ with the sum taken over even values of $k$ only.

In that case, observe that $$\sum_{k=0}^N  \binom{N}{k} {\sqrt{x}}^k = (1+{\sqrt{x}})^N$$ (which you know) is the sum taken over even values of $k$ **plus** an unwanted sum taken over odd values of $k$, and $$\sum_{k=0}^N  \binom{N}{k}(-{\sqrt{x}})^k = (1-{\sqrt{x}})^N$$ is the sum taken over even values of $k$ **minus** the same unwanted sum taken over odd values of $k$.

I hope you don't mind if I leave you to combine the two to get the answer you need.

**Generalisation**

It doesn't have to be $\binom{N}{2k}$ in your original question.

Consider $\binom{N}{3k}$ instead. Take $\omega$ to be a primitive cube root of 1: that is, one whose $n$th power is 1 *if and only if* $n$ is divisible by 3. (To be explicit, $\omega=\frac12({-1±\sqrt{3}})$). Take the sum $$\sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{k=0}^N  \binom{N}{k} (\omega^i{\sqrt[3]{x}})^k$$ and note:

- This is the sum of three series each of whose sums you know.
- Leaving aside the binomial, the coefficient of $\sqrt[3]{x}^k$ is 3 when $k$ is divisible by 3 (because all the $\omega^k$ equal 1), and 0 when it isn't (because all the $\omega^k$ add up to 0).

So now you know how to get $$\sum_{k=0}^N  \binom{N}{k} {\sqrt[3]{x}}^k$$ with the sum taken over values of $k$ divisible by 3.

The same thing works for all other multiples, but I thought it would be more readable to use "3" rather than yet another variable.

Comment: Beat me to it. As a compact alternative, one can observe that $c_k=\frac12(1+(-1)^k)$ equals 1 for even $k$ and zero for odd. Therefore the sum can be rewritten as $\sum_{k=0}^N \binom{N}{k}c_k x^{k/2}$ which is then readily expanded.

Comment: That will give you $\sum{N\choose2k}x^{2k}$ instead of $\dots x^k$. So you will also have to use $\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: I guess that in the first sum you meant to write $x^{1/2}$, right? Anyway that's not important...this was really clever, thanks!

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I'll edit to correct.